# Disabled Textbox doesn't work after "design" changed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a weird issue with my textbox. I have a textbox with 2 buttons: save and modify. If I click on save I want to disable the textbox and if I click on modify enable it.

It doesn't work. I still can modify the text even after click on save. Other weird thing, I disabled the modify button but the fontcolor of the text doesn't change when I load my form. Why?

Here's my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Modifybutton.Enabled = false;
}    

private void Savebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameBox.Enabled = false;
    Savebutton.Enabled = false;
    Modifybutton.Enabled = true;
}

private void Modifybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameBox.Enabled = true;
    Savebutton.Enabled = true;
}
```

I change some graphics, i think the issue come from that...

```
this.NameBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.InfoText;
this.NameBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.NameBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.MenuBar;
this.NameBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(358, 50);
this.NameBox.Name = "NameBox";
this.NameBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 26);
this.NameBox.TabIndex = 2;
this.NameBox.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Right;

this.Modifybutton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.Modifybutton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(394, 161);
this.Modifybutton.Name = "Modifyinfo";
this.Modifybutton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(172, 32);
this.Modifybutton.TabIndex = 8;
this.Modifybutton.Text = "Modifier";
this.Modifybutton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

It worked fine with an another form, the exact same code. The only difference is the design. Thank you.

Comment: The first code you've added contains controls named `Modifybutton`, `Textbox1` and `Savebutton`, while the second code block contains `NameBox` and `ModifyInfo`. Are you setting properties of the correct controls?

Comment: i was wandering the same thing...

Comment: @jsls can you show the part where you're subscribing the events ? Either designer or code.

Comment: @jsls Ok, but which textbox are we talking about, `Textbox1` or `NameBox` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem, with disabling and font colors not changing:

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

> Sets the application-wide default for the UseCompatibleTextRendering property defined on certain controls. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hum doesn't change anything... Yes i have it !

Comment: Okay, what? @jsls.